# How to store server_key_rsa in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rsa, sftp

I need to store the server_key_rsa of my sftpServer in a docker-compose.yml but I don't know how to store it

It's look like that for now :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
***********************My Key bla bla bla.......
**********************************************
**********************************************
**********************************************
**********************************************
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

And I would like to store it like that:

server_key_rsa = Here should be the key.

I tried with "|" just before my key, I tried to change my key file to Base64, I tried "\n" between lines, I tried "the\nrsa\nkey", but those solutions failed..

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [secrets definition in the docker-compose.yml file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#secrets-configuration-reference), as of version 3.3 of the file format, does not support passing the content of the secret inside the docker-compose.yml file itself. The secret needs to be either external (predefined with `docker secret create secret_name -`) or from the contents of a separate file.

The syntax with an externally defined secret is:

```
secrets:
  my_first_secret:
    file: ./secret_data
  my_second_secret:
    external: true
```

And the syntax for a separate file containing your secret is:

```
secrets:
  my_first_secret:
    file: ./secret_data
  my_second_secret:
    external:
      name: redis_secret
```

Comment: I dont understand the utility of this.. It means I must have both ssh-keygen files in my project plus included it into my docker-compose.yml. What is the safety performance advantage ? I mean, I could simply call my server_key_rsa file which contain my key instead of call an env variable which contain the link of my server_key_rsa file.

Comment: I suspect it's done this way since secrets shouldn't be stored in an unencrypted state with a file that's checked into your version control. The typical use case with a secret is to create them externally. You can always open an issue in github asking for the ability to store secret data in your unencrypted yml file.

Comment: Hmm ok, I did some research and a lots of people already opened this issue on github. Nevermind, thanks for your help anyway :)